# Attaching a github actions artefact to an email report

Tags: github, github-actions

I've been searching [the](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/storing-workflow-data-as-artifacts) Github Actions doc, but not able to find anything related to attachments. There is `download-artefact` but I'm not sure if this is going to solve my issue.

I've a simple enough task - I've run a simple playwright test script, which has generated a report, which is uploaded using `upload-artefacts`.

I send emails of the run using [this](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/send-email).

I'm looking if the uploaded artefact can be attached in the email attachments, because in the `send-email` action, I can see an optional param to add attachments.

Sample repo for reproduction: https://github.com/zac11/scrape-stackoverflow-questions

Comment: What is your question? Looks like you have figured out everything and just need to configure the attachment file to send.

Comment: And that is what my question is? I don't know how the configuration has to be done - how to add the artefact under the `attachments` in the email action.

Comment: According to https://github.com/marketplace/actions/send-email#usage, you'll be specifying the filename e.g. `attachments: filename.ext`. As you're already sending an email (https://github.com/zac11/scrape-stackoverflow-questions/blob/9cf201d93c57b7b7f4017f9ad580e47cf5e46eaf/.github/workflows/playwright.yml#L33-L47), now you just need to configure the attachment file.

Comment: Looks like the repot is generated under `playwright-report` directory. You can zip it and then attach it with the email.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Compress and generate a zip file in a separate step and use that in attachments. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57013/zip-all-files-in-directory.